# Select specific data Google Sheets with Javascript without OATH on client side

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-sheets-api

I have an `<iframe>` which "url" needs to be dynamically and remotely changed. I don't want to define the "src" in the `<iframe>` but pass it through a variable.

Therefore, I created a Google Sheets file with two cells: A1 is the title ("URL"), B1 is the actual url (eg. https://youtube.com/...) that will be manually changed from time to time.

I activated Google Sheets API.

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "range": "'RangeTitle'!A1:Z1000",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "URL",
      "https://www.youtube.com/..."
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is the example code it provides:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <!--
    BEFORE RUNNING:
    ---------------
    1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
       and check the quota for your project at
       https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
    2. Get access keys for your application. See
       https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#get-access-keys-for-your-application
    3. For additional information on authentication, see
       https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample
    -->
    <script>
    function makeApiCall() {
      var params = {
        // The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
        spreadsheetId: 'my-spreadsheet-id',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
        range: 'my-range',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // How values should be represented in the output.
        // The default render option is ValueRenderOption.FORMATTED_VALUE.
        valueRenderOption: '',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // How dates, times, and durations should be represented in the output.
        // This is ignored if value_render_option is
        // FORMATTED_VALUE.
        // The default dateTime render option is [DateTimeRenderOption.SERIAL_NUMBER].
        dateTimeRenderOption: '',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
      };

      var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(params);
      request.then(function(response) {
        // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
        console.log(response.result);
      }, function(reason) {
        console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    }

    function initClient() {
      var API_KEY = '';  // TODO: Update placeholder with desired API key.

      var CLIENT_ID = '';  // TODO: Update placeholder with desired client ID.

      // TODO: Authorize using one of the following scopes:
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
      var SCOPE = '';

      gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'clientId': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPE,
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
      }).then(function() {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSignInStatus);
        updateSignInStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      });
    }

    function handleClientLoad() {
      gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    function updateSignInStatus(isSignedIn) {
      if (isSignedIn) {
        makeApiCall();
      }
    }

    function handleSignInClick(event) {
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }

    function handleSignOutClick(event) {
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
    }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
    <button id="signin-button" onclick="handleSignInClick()">Sign in</button>
    <button id="signout-button" onclick="handleSignOutClick()">Sign out</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I filled the required fields. However, in the end, it requires the user to login to read the data. Therefore I would like to ask you:

1. If there is a way to read Google Sheets API data without OATH login from the users' side.
2. How can I pass the URL from B1 cell to the `<iframe src="">` as a variable.

Finally, I am open to another way to achieve the same result (dynamically pass the url to the `<iframe src="">` from an external source).

Comment: 1. fulfil the request via your server - i.e. a request comes from the browser to your server, and your server does the *authenticated* communication with google sheets API - 2. you stick the response in the `.src` property of that iframe

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to use Sheets API without login from the user account. If that is correct, then you could [create a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount) to reach your goal. Then you could [delegate domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) from the Admin console. By that way, you only have to OAuth 2.0 login from the service account and use it to access user's data. Please, ask me any additional doubt.